# How to delete duplicates in trigger

Tags: trigger

The following SOQL seems to identify duplicates in our object named training__c.
How to get a trigger to remove one of each duplicate?

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName, Start_Date__c, Name, count(Id) 
FROM Training__c 
WHERE Start_Date__c = THIS_YEAR 
GROUP BY LastName, FirstName, Name, Start_Date__c 
HAVING count(Id)>1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triggers can't really delete duplicates since they require a DML event to occur

The simplest solution if this is a cleanup option, is to use Data Loader to select the rows, use Excel to pick up the duplicates, and then Data Loader to delete the duplicates.

If this is an ongoing problem with new records coming in, use SFDC Duplicate Management to prevent new duplicates.

Comment: Totally agree with you @cropedy. Also if you are looking for a more automated way to manage duplicates in the future. You might want to take a look at a few solutions on the Appexchange like Cloudingo.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @cropredy answer, you'll want to make certain that these "duplicate" records aren't just "duplicates". They may contain additional information that you'll want to merge with the other record(s).

So, it's not just a case of deleting "duplicates", but also one of merging, updating or upserting records as they're being created using the duplicate management features. There could be valuable information to your org in one of the records that you delete if you choose unwisely. Choosing which one to remove is not something you want to do casually.